# Does the 2-Legged OAuth 2.0 meets HIPAA compliance?

Tags: restful-authentication

I'm about to start coding a new RESTful service with the CRUD methods and it needs to meet the HIPAA compliance, so I'm wondering if the 2-Legged OAuth 2.0 fits on that requirement.

Is there any source I can look at, so I can confirm if yes or no? I did a quick Google search, but could not find anything in detailed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any document on this? Have similar use case to host our application in HIPPA compliance based environment. Does HIPPA enforce 1 user 1 session guidelines?